# A complicated integral.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to find the closed form of the following integral:
$$
\int_{c_9}^{c_7} e^{-[f_5(z_2) + z_2]} (1 - e^{-2 z_2})^{L-1} dz_2,
$$
where
$$
f_5(z_2) = \rho^{-1} [2^{f_4(z_2)} - 1], \tag{1}
$$
$$
f_4(z_2) = \frac{R_1 \log_2(1 + \rho z_2)}{2 [\log_2(1 + \rho z_2) - R_1]}, \tag{2}
$$
$L \geq 1,L \in \mathbb{N}, c_7 > c_9 > 0, R_1 > 0,$ and $\rho >0$. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Closed form??? I'd suggest numeical methods for this beast.

Comment: @mickep Thank you for your comment. :-)